# Strange behavior in jQuery error responseText from WCF service

Tags: jquery, asp.net, wcf

I have a WCF service running in IIS with the following method:

```
public void Test()
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 500;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("You cannot do this.");
}
```

On my client HTML page I have the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'MyService.svc/Test',
            data: '',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert('success');
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert(result.responseText);
            }
        });
});
```

The error callback is invoked but the responseText is always only two chars: "Yo". I inspected the response and it appears to only be returning a content-length of 2. What is going on here? Why am I not receiving the full content of my response?

Answer (score 0):

Does your message truncate when you raise an exception?

```
public void Test()
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 500;
    throw new Exception("This is a test");
}
```